# Dynamic Page name in odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

I have six pages in my form which can be deleted/created by user. Is it possible to change the page name dynamically in Odoo forms? For example if the page strings are Page 1, Page 2 and so on.... If user deletes Page 1, Page 2's name should be changed as Page 1.

I could not find any solution in Google :/

Comment: Do you mean the pages in the notebooks? The tab names?

Comment: Yes pages under notebooks. Is it possible to change names dynamically ?